# Informar a un Service que se ha hecho click en un botón

Tags: android, servicio, broadcastreceiver

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android que no es más que una aplicación GPS para practicar deporte (por aprender).

Tengo un `Service` que implementa un `LocationListener` que recoge toda la información del GPS para calcular posición (latitude, longitude), altura, etc.

Este `Service` envía la información al `Activity` mediante un `sendBroadcast` para actualizar el layout (la vista). En el `Activity` tengo un `BroadcastReceiver` para recibir estos mensajes.

Ahora bien, ¿cómo puedo informar a este `Service` que en el `Activity` el usuario ha pinchado en el botón de "Pause" para que deje de enviarle información de localización? Es decir, la comunicación, pero al revés.

Os dejo el código del Service:

```java
public class GpsTrackerService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = GpsTrackerService.class.getSimpleName();

// Action for location change and its extra data.
public static final String LOCATION_CHANGE_ACTION = "gpstrackerservice.LOCATION_CHANGE";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_LATITUDE = "extra_location_latitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_LONGITUDE = "extra_location_longitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_ACCURACY = "extra_location_accuracy";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_ALTITUDE = "extra_location_altitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_TIME = "extra_location_time";

// Action for gps provider disabled and enabled.
public static final String LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_DISABLED_ACTION =
        "gpstrackerservice.GPS_DISABLED";
public static final String LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED_ACTION =
        "gpstrackerservice.GPS_ENABLED";

// Contains if this service ir running or not.
private static boolean sIsRunning = false;

// Location manager and configuration.
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

// The location listener.
private android.location.LocationListener mLocationListener =
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

/**
 * An inner class for location listener.
 */
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    /**
     * When loation is change it send via broadcast the information to the all registered
     * receivers.
     *
     * @param location
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);

        // Creates the intent, the location entity addint id to the extra and send de broadcast.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        es.rgmf.etroped.data.entity.Location locationEntity =
                new es.rgmf.etroped.data.entity.Location();
        locationEntity.setLatitude(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        locationEntity.setLongitude(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        locationEntity.setAccuracy(mLastLocation.getAccuracy());
        locationEntity.setGpsAltitude(mLastLocation.getAltitude());
        locationEntity.setBearing(mLastLocation.getBearing());
        locationEntity.setSpeed(mLastLocation.getSpeed());
        locationEntity.setTime(mLastLocation.getTime());

        bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_LOCATION, locationEntity);*/

        intent.setAction(LOCATION_CHANGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_LATITUDE, mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_ACCURACY, mLastLocation.getAccuracy());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_ALTITUDE, mLastLocation.getAltitude());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_TIME, mLastLocation.getTime());

        //intent.putExtras(bundle);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * When provider is disabled then it sends via broadcast the information to all registered
     * receivers.
     *
     * @param provider The provider has been disabled (gps, for example).
     */
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);

        if (provider.equals("gps")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_DISABLED_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);

        if (provider.equals("gps")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

    // Initialize location manager.
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    // Prepares the location manager for updates and sets the flag sIsRunning to true. From this
    // moment it can says that service is running.
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListener
        );
        sIsRunning = true;
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();

    // Stop service in foreground.
    stopForeground(true);

    // It is not running.
    sIsRunning = false;

    // Remove listener.
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
}

public static boolean isRunning() {
    return sIsRunning;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las actividad se pueden comunicar directamente con los servicios utilizando Binder. Esto le proporciona al cliente acceso directo a los métodos públicos incluidos en el servicio. Puedes leer un poco más de esto en Android investigando sobre IPC (Inter Process Communication)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=es-419

Otra forma básica usando las mismas herramientas que ya estás utilizando, sería registrar un broadcast receiver como el que tienes an la actividad del lado del servicio. Entonces podrías emitir desde la actividad cuando presionan el botón y subscribirte en el servicio. Es la misma lógica que usas en la actividad para recibir los eventos del servicio solo que intercambias los papeles y envías una acción que puedas identificar.

Otras dos formas utilizando librerías extra sería usar un bus de eventos como EventBus o programación reactiva usando RxJava